# Increasing extent of Raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, extents

I have a Raster, which covers only the southern part of the country, like this:

[image]

I wish to have a Raster, which covers the entire country (including the North part)? The northern part should have the nodata values.

How do I do this using GDAL or QGIS?

( I do not have ArcGIS, so I can't use the answer given here: [Increasing raster extent by filling extent with no data using ArcGIS Desktop without Spatial Analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111951/how-to-increase-raster-extent-by-filling-extent-with-no-data-using-arcgis-deskto))

I tried using `gdalwarp`'s `-te` parameter; It was successful in reducing the extent, but did not extend the extent to the Northern part.

Comment: create a constant raster https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/CreateConstantRaster.py the size you want and mosaic http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html...

Comment: Which GDAL version and how was your command like? In http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206161/enlarge-bounding-box-from-a-smaller-one-in-gdal/206169#206169 gdalwarp with -te did work, as well as gdal_translate with -projwin.

Comment: @user30184: I have 2.1.0;

Comment: Gdalwarp does work for me. I took a small image and run `gdalwarp -te -400000 6000000 1500000 9000000 test.tif out.tif`. Result checked with gdalinfo `Lower Left  ( -400000.000, 6000000.000)
Upper Right ( 1500000.000, 9000000.000)`. Perhaps you should make a new test. Make sure that the target image does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggested workflow:

1. Create a polygon of the extent you want to cover
2. rasterize the polygon
3. fill it with a nodata value using gdalcalc
4. add the existing raster with gdalwarp without the `-overwrite` option.

Answer (score 10):

**For future readers**

As `user30184` mentioned in the comments, `gdalwarp` is also working and easier than the accepted answer. Run the following command with your specific arguments to change (increase is also working) your raster extent:

`gdalwarp.exe -te xmin ymin xmax ymax old_extent.tif new_extent.tif`

Ensure that your outputfile (in this case `new_extent.tif`) doesn't exist before running the command!

Answer (score 2):

A very simple process. Just right-click on the raster for which has to be changed and click *Save As*. Further, put the extent manually and click OK.

[image]

Comment: This is the best way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

GDAL didn't work for me, but I found this super easy workaround in QGIS:

Open Raster Calculater

Input the raster layer you want to expand

In the Result box - select a layer which has the area you want your raster to cover and click 'Current Layer Extent' or define the X,Y,etc values yourself.