# Cannot increase interpolated raster extents for QGIS map

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, mapping

I have created a map of a lake, and I am interpolating some water quality values over the top by raster grid (inverse distance to nearest neighbour). I have successfully created the three water quality layers to present as 3 separate maps, but I want to firstly expand the extent of the water quality layers so that they cover the entire bottom of the lake outline, so that I can then clip them to the outline of the lake.

I have tried the answers suggested on the previous most relevant question: [Increasing extent of Raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209139/increasing-extent-of-raster)

and none of these options have worked for me. I have included screenshots of my map and the errors I get when trying to increase the extents

[image]
[image]

Comment: The error says that your file system is read-only. What kind of file system do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure, i'm working off an M1 mac so i'd presume its AFPS? I have saved all of my files for this map to the same folder and then generated the interpolation. I haven't had this issue with any of my previous layers though?

Comment: Have you tried to save into some other folder? Do you already have an older test.tif file in the folder?

Comment: I deleted the fie that it originally came from, I will attempt to expand the raster again after keeping the original file of the un-interpolated data

Comment: Was your original file perhaps the `test.tif` file, and did you try to save the new one with the same name? That is not possible, you must create a new file.