# Excluding NoData zones in zonal statistics as table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, nodata

I'm trying to calculate mean values of a raster within buffer zones. In the zonal statistics as table tool window, I unchecked 'Ignore NoData in Calculations' so that there is no mean calculated for zones which contain no data. It worked first with small 100m buffer zones. But this doesn't work with larger 500m buffer zones. The result still contains almost all buffers even if they contain no data cells from the raster.

Any idea why this happens?

The raster is 30m resolution.

Comment: If you uncheck 'Ignore NoData in Calculations' the NoData are not ignored....

Comment: Yes they are not ignored and those zones have then no mean calculated, which is exactly what I want. But mean is still being calculated even for those zones with nodata.

Comment: Could you include an image of the raster with buffers overlaid transparently? A raster can have no data values stored in its cells, or there can be no data because you are exceeding the extent of the raster. If the later is the case here, I think the result won't be what you want unless you add a region of no data cells to the boundary of your raster a la https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111951/increasing-raster-extent-by-filling-extent-with-no-data-using-arcgis-desktop-wit

Comment: @nrp1000 okay but this has nothing to do with my question. Its not about extent. There are no data cells right there in the middle of the raster, so, within the raster extent and buffers are on top of those no data cells in the middle. But those buffers are not being excluded by the zonal stats as table tool when I keep Ignore NoData in Calculations unchecked.